# Public iVar; readonly from other classes

Tags: objective-c

What is the best way to make an iVar writeable by its owning class, but readonly by other classes?

Is there more than one way?

The only way I can think of is to set a `@property (readonly)` for the iVar, but not use dot notation inside the owning class (which I'm guessing wouldn't work with readonly), and in the owning class just reference it directly, without dot notation, then in other class, reference it with dot notation.

But I'm curious if there are other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a property read/write just for the implementation. You do this using a class extension, or anonymous category, in your implementation. Easier to demonstrate so, for example, in your .h:

```
@interface MyClass

@property (readonly) NSInteger age;
...

@end
```

and in your .m:

```
@interface MyClass () // class extension/anonymous category for private methods & properties
                      // implementation of these go in main @implementation

@property (readwrite) NSInteger age;
...

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize age;
...

@end
```

Now you can use the property within your class read/write and from outside as read-only.

You do the same for private methods.

*[Note: This is Objective-C so the above isn't bullet proof - there are ways around it to call the properties setter - but the compiler will flag errors which assign to the property from outside the class.]*

After comments:

*[Note 2: an anonymous category/class extension is very similar to a named category. The former **must** be implemented in the main implementation, the latter may be implemented in an `@implementation classname (categoryname)` or in the main implementation. Furthermore only the main interface, the interface for a class extension/anonymous category, and the main implementation may declare instance variables; interfaces and implementations for named categories may not. Properties may be declared in both anonymous and named categories, however they may only be synthesized in the main implementation and not in named category implementations. This note is correct at press time, some of these features have changed as Objective-C/Xcode develops.]*

Comment: thanks; two followup questions: does it matter if you name the category -- i often see people putting `(Private)` for private declarations, what is the "way around" for another class to access a property's setter, even if the public property is readwrite?

Comment: I've made some edits to his original post, hopefully he will approve them, but the info as it stands is incorrect. This is a class extension not a category, 2 very different things.

Comment: @Lucas - "anonymous category" and "extension" are the same thing.

Comment: @andrewx - yes it does matter if you name the category. Named categories must be implemented in an `@interface class (category name)`; while anonymous categories aka extensions are implemented in the main `@implementation class`.

Comment: interesting, I see countless samples all over the web where named categories are implemented in the regular un-named implementation section; i'll know not to do this myself, but i've done for a while with no problems.

Comment: @CRD Ok thanks, just never heard of it called that before. Another key importance is that you can't create instance variables/properties in named categories, only extensions allow this.

Comment: @andrewx - Objective-C is a somewhat liberal language, partly due to its dynamic nature. An anonymous category/class extension *must* be implemented in the main `@implementation classname`; you **cannot** have an `@implementation classname ()`. An `@implementation classname (category name)` is for methods of a named category, but in fact you can implement a method from a named category in the main `@implementation classname` and even in an `@implementation classname (some other category name)` - the methods from all the categories simply become part of the class.

Comment: @Lucas - yes, instance variables can only be declared in the `@interface classname`, `@interface classname ()` and `@implementation classname`. Properties it seems are a little more messy, you can declare them in any category but you can only synthesize them in the main implementation, but you can directly implement them in categories.

Answer (score 0):

Use the private specifier for ivars and a class extension to define the accessor - that way the ivar is private to the class.

// FooClass.h
@interface FooClass : NSObject {
@private int boo;

}
@end

// FooClass.m

@interface FooClass () {

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) int boo;

@end

@implementation FooClass

@synthesize boo;
// ....

@end